# Acts_As_Votable Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying to figure out how to get ajax working with my Acts_As_Votable buttons.

Here is what I have right now.

---

**post_controller.rb**

```
def favorite
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.upvote_from current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end 
end

def unfavorite 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.unvote_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end 
end
```

---

**_post.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.voted_on? post  %>
  <%= link_to '<i style="color: red" class="fa fa-star"></i> Favorited'.html_safe, unfavorite_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "unfavorite" %>
<% else %> 
  <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-star"></i> Favorite'.html_safe, favorite_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "favorite" %>
<% end %>
```

---

**favorite.js.erb & unfavorite.js.erb**

```
$('#favorite').html("<i style='color: red' class='fa fa-star'></i> Favorited");

$('#unfavorite').html("<i class='fa fa-star'></i> Favorite");
```

---

Right now I have it partially working. I have two problems.

1. Each page contains multiple posts. How can I tell the format.js.erb file to target that spectific post's favoirte button. Right now, the jQuery only changes the first posts button, no matter where I click on the page. I've tried setting the link_to ids to favorite<%= post.id %> and then using favorite<%= post.id %> in the format.js file but that didn't work.
2. I want to change the format.js files to put the actual button into the div instead of just changing its text. So a user can toggle favorite and unfavorite without having to refresh the page. I've tried putting the link_to buttons inside the .html("") section but that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to submit a post request with ajax.

Thank you for the help! Let me know if you need any more code or I wasn't clear about something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `id` must be unique in one page. You should be able to append the `post.id` to your link:

**_post.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user.voted_on? post  %>
  <%= render 'unfavorite_link', post: post %>
<% else %> 
  <%= render 'favorite_link', post: post %>
<% end %>
```

**_favorite_link.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-star"></i> Favorite'.html_safe, favorite_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "favorite-#{post.id}" %>
```

**_unfavorite_link.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to '<i style="color: red" class="fa fa-star"></i> Favorited'.html_safe, unfavorite_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: true, id: "unfavorite-#{post.id}" %>
```

Instead of only setting the `html` using AJAX, you can use `replaceWith` which replaces the whole link, not just its inner HTML:

**favorite.js.erb**

```
$('#favorite-<%= @post.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render 'unfavorite_link', post: @post %>');
```

**unfavorite.js.erb**

```
$('#unfavorite-<%= @post.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render 'favorite_link', post: @post %>');
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you AbM! So I guess the trick here was to have my link in separate partials too. Thank you!

Comment: The partials are not required for the solution to work. They were just used to keep the code DRY. If for some reason you decided to change the html of the links, you would only change it in one location instead of changing it in both `_post.html.erb` and `(un)favorite.js.erb`

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. Thanks for clarifying!